# Laravel session not setting after logging in from a session timeout

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

We're currently developing with Laravel but we are having issues when a user was logged out because of session timeout. What we did for debugging was:

1. Set the session timeout to one minute.
2. Simply login. (everything was fine)
3. Waited for a minute before the session expires.
4. After the session expires, the system logged out.
5. Upon logging in again, the session wasn't set and returns no value.

Here's how we add the session at `LoginController.php`:

```
$hotelier = Hotelier::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->first();
$company = Company::find($hotelier->company_id);

Session::put('company_id', $hotelier->company_id);
Session::put('company_api_key', $company->api_key);
```

Here's our code upon logout at `AuthenticateUsers.php`

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Which session driver are you using?

Comment: We are using file as a session driver. @apokryfos

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, can you describe it a bit better?